# Use multiple colour schemes in symbology (one per heading) in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, symbology

I am trying to see if I can save time while symbolizing a layer in ArcGIS Pro. I use a polygon feature class that is grouped into multiple headings, each heading with 4-6 symbol classes. If I choose a colour scheme from the dropdown, it applies it across all the classes.

Is there a way to apply the colour scheme to only 1 of the headings, then select another heading and choose a different colour scheme?

I tried highlighting only one heading and changing the colour scheme but no luck.

In the meantime I've been forced to manually select a gradient of colours (ie. light blue to dark blue) for each heading, but this adds significant time for each map I create.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any feature in Pro that would allow this kind of symbology outside of how you are currently doing it.

My suggested work flow would be to export each sub heading to a new feature class- That is select by attribute to select sub heading 1, then use the "Export Features" tool in Pro to create a new feature class. then repeat until all of your sub headings are broken out into new feature classes. You would then only be applying one level of gradient symbology.

I may be wrong, but this is how I would do it.

Comment: Adding the layer several time and applying a definition query to each one achieve the same and doesn't require to create new layers with the added bonus that any change to the data will be reflected on the map without needing to re-export the layer....

Comment: I thought of this after the fact, and figured someone would chime in before I could make it back here.